# Unchecked Call to 'execute(Params...)' as a member of raw type 'android.os.AsyncTask'

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm following the google android tutorial on Udacity but in the specified code, I'm getting the following warning:

> Unchecked Call to 'execute(Params...)' as a member of raw type 'android.os.AsyncTask'

on this code:

```
DoSomethingTask myTask = new DoSomethingTask();
myTask.execute(); // Warning here
```

DoSomethingTask:

```
public class DoSomethingTask extends AsyncTask {

    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain this warning and how to fix it? It seems it should work according to the instructions...

Comment: By "error" you mean "warning"?

Comment: I think it is cause by the params for the Task, try to extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> and remove the Object[] params in the task. Or try extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> and add an object in execute(someObject)

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis That was it! Although I distinctly remember typing that in originally... Not sure how that disappeared! Can you post an answer so I can mark it answered?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The warning is caused by the params for the task. Try to use:

```
extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    protected Object doInBackground() {
    }
}
```

or use:

```
extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void>{
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    }
}
myTask.execute(anyObject);
```

Explanation:

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) document explains the meaning of the three types for AsyncTask.

> 1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
> 2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
> 3. Result, the type of the result of the background computation.

Comment: What does this warning mean?! @zp_x

Comment: @ChintanShah hi, i have added an explanation. Basically to use it, just make sure the types are matched correctly.

Comment: Thank you for adding explanation. @zp_x

Answer (score 3):

change

```
AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            return "";
        }
    };

    asyncTask.execute();
```

to

```
AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            return "";
        }
    };

    asyncTask.execute();
```

AsyncTask reference need the same as AsyncTask Class ,and IDE will not warning 。